# How to break ping command without waiting for its complete output in expect programming?

Tags: expect

I am new to expect programming. In my script i need to run multiple ping commands.

I am running below mentioned command: `ping $ip rep 100 size 1500`

If connection is successful than its all good, but if ping response will not come, then it will keep pinging device till 100 rep, which is taking a lot of time. I want to break it in between and switch to next command if i got output of command like this:

Type escape sequence to abort. Sending 100, 1500-byte ICMP Echos to $ip, timeout is 2 seconds: .......

I have tried breaking it with regex and different ASCII codes, but every other option is working only after 100 pings to device.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sounds like an XY-problem, why not lower response  needed ? You might also want to have a look at `timeout` command.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use `timeout` to set a maximum duration for the whole command.  So you can let `ping` run 100 pings but if it can't complete in 200 seconds (total) then it will just exit.

```
timeout 200 ping $ip rep 100 size 1500
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested:

```
spawn ping ...
expect {
    "Type escape sequence to abort. Sending 100, 1500-byte ICMP Echos to $ip, timeout is 2 seconds:" {
        send -- "\x03"  ;# send Ctrl-C
        exp_continue
    }
    eof
}
```

Comment: Looks right: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23838130/453851

Answer (score 0):

How about pinging only a predefined number of times? E.g.

```
 ping -c 5
```